# for each type 13 error vba

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I am a new vba user and I am having trouble with a type 13 error on a loop. 
I currently have two workbooks. One with around 19 sheets that I want to copy data from, and the other workbook where I want to paste all the data which will feed into my pivot tables. Is this method even the best way to go about this?

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
Dim COOupdate As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nrow As Long
Dim destrange As Range


Set COOupdate = Workbooks.Open("file path & file name")
Set ws = ActiveSheet
nrow = 2
Set destrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("b" & nrow)

COOupdate.Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Data Sheet" Or "Parameters" Then
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5:B71,E5:E71,H5:H71,K5:K71,N5:N71,Q5:Q71").Copy 
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("b" & nrow)
    ActiveSheet.Range("b2").Copy 
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("a2:a68")
    nrow = nrow + destrange.Rows.Count
  ActiveSheet.Next.Select
End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Code such as `Worksheets(5)` refers to the fifth sheet in the tab order - which can be changed by the user by dragging sheets to different positions.  Better to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 5")` to refer to a sheet by its tab name or just `Sheet5` to refer to it by its codename, providing it's in `ThisWorkbook` (code name is the sheet name _not_ in brackets in the _Project Explorer_.

Answer (score 0):

Your OR syntax wasn't quite right, plus no need to activate sheets. Change your loop to this. Your second copy appears to be overwriting though.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not (ws.Name = "Data Sheet" Or ws.Name = "Parameters") Then
        ws.Range("B5:B71,E5:E71,H5:H71,K5:K71,N5:N71,Q5:Q71").Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("b" & nrow)
        ws.Range("b2").Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("a2:a68")
        nrow = nrow + destrange.Rows.Count
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @SJR got to the crux of the problem by pointing out the problem with `If ActiveSheet.Name = "Data Sheet" Or "Parameters" Then`.

I haven't tested this code, but it should work and show some improvements to your original code:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
    Dim COOupdate As Workbook
    Dim dest_ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set COOupdate = Workbooks.Open("file path & file name")

    'Going to paste to this sheet:
    Set dest_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination Sheet") 'Update name as required.

    'Going to copy from all sheets, except "Data Sheet" & "Parameters"
    For Each ws In COOupdate.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Data Sheet", "Parameters"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                ws.Range("B5:B71,E5:E71,H5:H71,K5:K71,N5:N71,Q5:Q71").Copy _
                    Destination:=LastCell(dest_ws).Offset(1)
        End Select
    Next ws

    COOupdate.Close
    'ThisWorkbook.Save  'Uncomment after tested.

End Sub

'Returns reference to last cell containing data on the worksheet.
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```